# intellij- cannot resolve symbol 'support'

Tags: android

I am new to intellij13 and just imported my Android project into it. however get the following errors and tried adding dependencies but cannot work.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

those are my imports

Comment: it might help if you actually add the errors you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going out on the limb here, but you probably need to add **android-support-v4.jar** to your project dependencies (in the **/libs** folder). If you are using Gradle, then add:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

in your **build.gradle** file

Comment: thanks that works fine. actually you also include all the jars in the  libs folder to ur project from Project structure>>libraries section. then add folder.

Comment: i think my sherlock library isnt being seeen much as i have added dependencies to it. is there anything i haven done or done right

Comment: @user3829537 its hard to say from you post. Please, post the error you are getting or a screenshot